# elasticsearch return all result with criteria

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to do a research with elastic search (6.1) where all result are returned if the criteria 'searchText' is empty.

Actually, I have this :

```
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'should': [
        {
          'match_all': {}
        },
        {
          'nested': {
            'path': 'person',
            'query': {
              'and': {
                'should': [
                  {'match': {'person.name': searchText}},
                  {'match': {'person.noCtr': searchText}},
                  {'match': {'person.noIde': searchText}}
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

With this, when searchText is empty, I have all result. But if searchText is filled, all results are still displayed (no matter the criterias)

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "**minimum_should_match**" : 1 in your query so that result will be displayed only if one of the "should" clause is true.

Incase you want to search in multiple fields for same values, you can explore more on "**_all**" ("include in all")

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/mapping-all-field.html